# batch file use inflated zip file as a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, unzip

example:

```
C:\Users\Jeffery\Downloads>unzip -o "1942 (Japan, USA).zip" -d %temp% | find ".nes"
inflating: C:/Users/Jeffery/AppData/Local/Temp/1942 (Japan, USA).nes
```

I want the inflated filename into a variable

```
SET _game="C:/Users/Jeffery/AppData/Local/Temp/1942 (Japan, USA).nes"
```

so that I can use it in my launcher

```
C:/Users/Jeffery/Downloads/nesemu.exe %_game%
```

Comment: You mean you want the filename it extracted from the zip file. You can't put the whole contents of a file into a single variable.

Comment: updated question with better example

Comment: Use a FOR command to get a list of files in the directory.